# Does OpenCV's Cascade classifier use multiple cores?

Tags: c++, opencv, cascade-classifier

Recently I wrote my own modified version (single threaded CPU's code) of Cascade Classifier which uses OpenCV's XML file.

I want to compare my bare VJ algorithm with OpenCV's. So I disabled OpenCL and when I run OpenCV's one it takes 19-23ms to process whole image, while my code takes 39-49ms which is 2 times slower.

I suspect it's because I have 2 cores in my CPU and they used parallel for loops to increase efficiency. Am I right?

If wrong how much impact do parallel loops in OpenCV's code have in overall performance?

Comment: Check [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp) and find out. Yes, they use parallel for.

Comment: I've checked it and that's why I mentioned parallel loops. But what I wanna know is how much effect do those loops have. Does dividing program into 2 cores mean 2 times faster process?